# Highlight part of image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to implement a feature where you can highlight part of an image and crop it. I've seen an app called 'My Cam' and it have some awesome highlight mechanism, I think it probably uses color detection, see how I was able to highlight the silver part of the monitor easily:

[image]

I'm new to Quartz2D so please excuse my ignorance, I was able to achieve basic highlighting over the Image, this is a code sample:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:_frontView];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_frontView.frame.size);
    [_frontView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _frontView.frame.size.width, _frontView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    //CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 25.0);
    //CGContextSetShadowWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGSizeMake(0, 0), 50, [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor]);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [[UIColor colorWithRed:109/255.0f green:110/255.0f blue:112/255.0f alpha:0.5f] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeOverlay);

    CGContextAddPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), path);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    _frontView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(lastPath, nil, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(lastPath, nil, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated, I reckon doing something like in the image needs months of work for a beginner. I was hoping to find something on github but my searches failed.

Comment: This subject that your trying to work on, is related to morphological processing. and is similar to **Magnetic lasso tool** in photoshop. in the **Matlab** you can find some functions for this

Comment: Check this article out! http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/08/28/how-to-implement-a-magic-wand-tool/